# Does the multiplication of the recursive calls affect the master's theorem?

Tags: time-complexity, master-theorem

I have the following code snippet that I need to calculate its complexity.

```
int T2 (int n) {
    int c = 0;
    if (n < 2) 
        return 1; 
    else
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i = i + 1)
            c++;
    return c + 4 * T2 (n / 9) * T2 (n / 9) + T2 (n / 9);
}
```

As this is a recursive function where we are dividing n by 9 in each call, I believe that master's theorem apply here. If we consider that "a" is equal to the number of subproblems, can I simply consider a=3 when applying master's theorem or does the multiplication of calls change that?
That is, can I say that T(n) = 3T(n/9) + O(n)?
where O(n) came from the for loop in the algorithm:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i = i + 1)
    c++;
```

Comment: This is an algorithmic analysis question, not a computer programming question. (The answer to this question is not a computer program.) Though I find it odd that you think that the master theorem applies despite the recursion not meeting the requirements of the master theorem. The master theorem requires that the recursion be expressible at T(n) = a * T(n/b) + f(n), where a and b are constants.

Comment: @RaymondChen Actually, I had this question in an exam and I left it unanswered last month. However, the instructor wrote beside my empty answer that it could be solved using the master's theorem and I found it odd just like you did that's why I asked here when I got my paper back.

Comment: Maybe there is a nonlinear version of the master theorem. This is a great opportunity to take advantage of the instructor's office hours